# OpenCL - what happens if GPU memory is larger than system RAM

Tags: linux, memory, opencl, gpu

We have an opencl application than runs with single nvidia C2075 (6GB Mem) in a machine with 12 GB RAM.

We had set up a new machine with 12GB RAM and an AMD W9100 GPU (16GB Mem) ( and made sure everything correct by running simple opencl apps).

Now the same opencl application crashes in the new machine. We have found that during execution some of the memory allocations fail. Increasing the system memory to 24GB made the application work.

(the application works in all single gpu machines where gpu memory > system memory. all machines are suse linux enterprise server 64bit)

How do you conclude this scenario?
I thought the GPU was mapping its whole 16GB onto the system RAM, there by causing memory starvation. But going through /proc/iomem and lspci -v, i could not see a 16GB window. 
Does the GPU really map its memory to system memory?

Thanks for the help

Comment: It's not just simply a matter of the application itself choosing its data size based on the available device memory, and allocating itself a chunk of system RAM to match?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what would happen, but I believe that a machine with more GPU memory than RAM is grossly unbalanced (and you could experiment [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29)...). RAM is quite cheap these days, so go buy some more!

<sup>You machine is probably unbalanced, since in numerical computations not everything is happenning inside the GPU. You need to do some data management (at least `malloc` and IO and overall computation control), and that requires the data to sometimes sit in the process memory space, which practically should mean in RAM.</sup>

> How do you conclude this scenario? I thought the GPU was mapping its whole 16GB onto the system RAM, there by causing memory starvation.

Certainly not. The GPU memory is [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)-ed, and this means in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), not physical one.

AFAIK, the GPU memory is seen (by software) as RAM, even if it is probably several times slower (for processor access) than ordinary RAM (because the PCI bus linking a graphics card to the motherboard is much slower than the RAM bus linking RAM to the processor)

I have a low-end NVIDIA GPU and I have 16 GbRAM and only 1 or 2 Gb of GPU memory, but:

```
 % sudo cat /proc/$(pidof /usr/bin/X)/maps
7f18a942a000-7f18ad42a000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 76611587                   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7f18ad42a000-7f18adae5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f18ade6e000-7f18ae658000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f18af0f9000-7f18affce000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f18b02ce000-7f18b12ae000 rw-s 103ada000 00:06 14729                     /dev/dri/card0

7f18b656e000-7f18b656f000 rw-p 00025000 08:02 2229454                    /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
7f18b65c3000-7f18b6643000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 76546049                   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7f18b6663000-7f18b66c3000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 76742661                   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7f18b66c3000-7f18b6743000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 76709892                   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7f18b6743000-7f18b674f000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 534519                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
7f18b674f000-7f18b694e000 ---p 0000c000 08:02 534519                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
7f18b694e000-7f18b694f000 r--p 0000b000 08:02 534519                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
7f18b694f000-7f18b6950000 rw-p 0000c000 08:02 534519                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
7f18b6950000-7f18b6971000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 536346                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
7f18b6971000-7f18b6b70000 ---p 00021000 08:02 536346                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
7f18b6b70000-7f18b6b71000 r--p 00020000 08:02 536346                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
7f18b6b71000-7f18b6b72000 rw-p 00021000 08:02 536346                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
7f18b6b72000-7f18b6b88000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 2229443                    /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so
7f18b6b88000-7f18b6d88000 ---p 00016000 08:02 2229443                    /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so
7f18b6d88000-7f18b6d89000 r--p 00016000 08:02 2229443                    /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so
7f18b6d89000-7f18b6d8a000 rw-p 00017000 08:02 2229443                    /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so
7f18b6d8a000-7f18b6d90000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 534517                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
7f18b6d90000-7f18b6f8f000 ---p 00006000 08:02 534517                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
7f18b6f8f000-7f18b6f90000 r--p 00005000 08:02 534517                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
7f18b6f90000-7f18b6f91000 rw-p 00006000 08:02 534517                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
7f18b6f91000-7f18b6fc2000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 2232215                    /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
7f18b6fc2000-7f18b71c2000 ---p 00031000 08:02 2232215                    /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
7f18b71c2000-7f18b71c3000 r--p 00031000 08:02 2232215                    /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
7f18b71c3000-7f18b71c7000 rw-p 00032000 08:02 2232215                    /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
7f18b71c7000-7f18b71cc000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 534404                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
7f18b71cc000-7f18b73cb000 ---p 00005000 08:02 534404                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
7f18b73cb000-7f18b73cc000 r--p 00004000 08:02 534404                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
7f18b73cc000-7f18b73cd000 rw-p 00005000 08:02 534404                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
7f18b73cd000-7f18b73ee000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 530987                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7f18b73ee000-7f18b75ed000 ---p 00021000 08:02 530987                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7f18b75ed000-7f18b75ee000 r--p 00020000 08:02 530987                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7f18b75ee000-7f18b75ef000 rw-p 00021000 08:02 530987                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7f18b75ef000-7f18b75f4000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 534560                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
7f18b75f4000-7f18b77f4000 ---p 00005000 08:02 534560                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
7f18b77f4000-7f18b77f5000 r--p 00005000 08:02 534560                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
7f18b77f5000-7f18b77f6000 rw-p 00006000 08:02 534560                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
7f18b77f6000-7f18b77f8000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 534558                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
7f18b77f8000-7f18b79f7000 ---p 00002000 08:02 534558                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
7f18b79f7000-7f18b79f8000 r--p 00001000 08:02 534558                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
7f18b79f8000-7f18b79f9000 rw-p 00002000 08:02 534558                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
7f18b79f9000-7f18b79fb000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 534554                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0
7f18b79fb000-7f18b7bfa000 ---p 00002000 08:02 534554                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0
7f18b7bfa000-7f18b7bfb000 r--p 00001000 08:02 534554                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0
7f18b7bfb000-7f18b7bfc000 rw-p 00002000 08:02 534554                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0
7f18b7bfc000-7f18b7c00000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 534543                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
7f18b7c00000-7f18b7dff000 ---p 00004000 08:02 534543                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
7f18b7dff000-7f18b7e00000 r--p 00003000 08:02 534543                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
7f18b7e00000-7f18b7e01000 rw-p 00004000 08:02 534543                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
7f18b7e01000-7f18b7e18000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 534556                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
7f18b7e18000-7f18b8017000 ---p 00017000 08:02 534556                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
7f18b8017000-7f18b8019000 r--p 00016000 08:02 534556                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
7f18b8019000-7f18b801a000 rw-p 00018000 08:02 534556                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
7f18b801a000-7f18b8156000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 530991                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7f18b8156000-7f18b8355000 ---p 0013c000 08:02 530991                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7f18b8355000-7f18b8357000 r--p 0013b000 08:02 530991                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7f18b8357000-7f18b835c000 rw-p 0013d000 08:02 530991                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7f18b835c000-7f18b835d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f18b835d000-7f18b835e000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 534541                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
7f18b835e000-7f18b855d000 ---p 00001000 08:02 534541                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
7f18b855d000-7f18b855e000 r--p 00000000 08:02 534541                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
7f18b855e000-7f18b855f000 rw-p 00001000 08:02 534541                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
7f18b855f000-7f18b8564000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 559997                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7f18b8564000-7f18b8763000 ---p 00005000 08:02 559997                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7f18b8763000-7f18b8764000 r--p 00004000 08:02 559997                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7f18b8764000-7f18b8765000 rw-p 00005000 08:02 559997                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7f18b8765000-7f18b8767000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 560382                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7f18b8767000-7f18b8966000 ---p 00002000 08:02 560382                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7f18b8966000-7f18b8967000 r--p 00001000 08:02 560382                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7f18b8967000-7f18b8968000 rw-p 00002000 08:02 560382                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7f18b8968000-7f18b8979000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 530998                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7f18b8979000-7f18b8b78000 ---p 00011000 08:02 530998                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7f18b8b78000-7f18b8b79000 r--p 00010000 08:02 530998                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7f18b8b79000-7f18b8b7a000 rw-p 00011000 08:02 530998                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7f18b8b7a000-7f18b8b9f000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 531500                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
7f18b8b9f000-7f18b8d9f000 ---p 00025000 08:02 531500                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
7f18b8d9f000-7f18b8da2000 r--p 00025000 08:02 531500                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
7f18b8da2000-7f18b8da3000 rw-p 00028000 08:02 531500                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
7f18b8da3000-7f18b8da4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f18b8da4000-7f18b8dca000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393404                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f18b8dca000-7f18b8fc9000 ---p 00026000 08:02 393404                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f18b8fc9000-7f18b8fcc000 r--p 00025000 08:02 393404                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f18b8fcc000-7f18b8fcd000 rw-p 00028000 08:02 393404                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f18b8fcd000-7f18b9063000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 531019                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0
7f18b9063000-7f18b9262000 ---p 00096000 08:02 531019                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0
7f18b9262000-7f18b9265000 r--p 00095000 08:02 531019                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0
7f18b9265000-7f18b9266000 rw-p 00098000 08:02 531019                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0
7f18b9266000-7f18b9267000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f18b9267000-7f18b92aa000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 2229456                    /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
7f18b92aa000-7f18b94a9000 ---p 00043000 08:02 2229456                    /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
7f18b94a9000-7f18b94ab000 r--p 00042000 08:02 2229456                    /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
7f18b94ab000-7f18b94af000 rw-p 00044000 08:02 2229456                    /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
7f18b94af000-7f18b94c5000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393444                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f18b94c5000-7f18b96c4000 ---p 00016000 08:02 393444                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f18b96c4000-7f18b96c5000 rw-p 00015000 08:02 393444                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f18b96c5000-7f18b96eb000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393438                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.50.0
7f18b96eb000-7f18b98ea000 ---p 00026000 08:02 393438                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.50.0
7f18b98ea000-7f18b98eb000 r--p 00025000 08:02 393438                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.50.0
7f18b98eb000-7f18b98ec000 rw-p 00026000 08:02 393438                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.50.0
7f18b98ec000-7f18b98f2000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 528151                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontenc.so.1.0.0
7f18b98f2000-7f18b9af1000 ---p 00006000 08:02 528151                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontenc.so.1.0.0
7f18b9af1000-7f18b9af2000 r--p 00005000 08:02 528151                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontenc.so.1.0.0
7f18b9af2000-7f18b9af4000 rw-p 00006000 08:02 528151                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontenc.so.1.0.0
7f18b9af4000-7f18b9b03000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393256                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
7f18b9b03000-7f18b9d02000 ---p 0000f000 08:02 393256                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
7f18b9d02000-7f18b9d03000 r--p 0000e000 08:02 393256                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
7f18b9d03000-7f18b9d04000 rw-p 0000f000 08:02 393256                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
7f18b9d04000-7f18b9da7000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 530811                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.11.1
7f18b9da7000-7f18b9fa7000 ---p 000a3000 08:02 530811                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.11.1
7f18b9fa7000-7f18b9fad000 r--p 000a3000 08:02 530811                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.11.1
7f18b9fad000-7f18b9fae000 rw-p 000a9000 08:02 530811                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.11.1
7f18b9fae000-7f18b9fc8000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393316                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f18b9fc8000-7f18ba1c7000 ---p 0001a000 08:02 393316                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f18ba1c7000-7f18ba1c8000 r--p 00019000 08:02 393316                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f18ba1c8000-7f18ba1c9000 rw-p 0001a000 08:02 393316                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f18ba1c9000-7f18ba1da000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393327                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.13.0
7f18ba1da000-7f18ba3d9000 ---p 00011000 08:02 393327                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.13.0
7f18ba3d9000-7f18ba3da000 r--p 00010000 08:02 393327                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.13.0
7f18ba3da000-7f18ba3db000 rw-p 00011000 08:02 393327                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.13.0
7f18ba3db000-7f18ba447000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393252                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1
7f18ba447000-7f18ba647000 ---p 0006c000 08:02 393252                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1
7f18ba647000-7f18ba648000 r--p 0006c000 08:02 393252                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1
7f18ba648000-7f18ba649000 rw-p 0006d000 08:02 393252                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1
7f18ba649000-7f18ba661000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393707                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7f18ba661000-7f18ba860000 ---p 00018000 08:02 393707                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7f18ba860000-7f18ba861000 r--p 00017000 08:02 393707                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7f18ba861000-7f18ba862000 rw-p 00018000 08:02 393707                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7f18ba862000-7f18ba866000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f18ba866000-7f18ba86d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393708                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
7f18ba86d000-7f18baa6c000 ---p 00007000 08:02 393708                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
7f18baa6c000-7f18baa6d000 r--p 00006000 08:02 393708                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
7f18baa6d000-7f18baa6e000 rw-p 00007000 08:02 393708                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
7f18baa6e000-7f18bac0d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393714                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f18bac0d000-7f18bae0d000 ---p 0019f000 08:02 393714                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f18bae0d000-7f18bae11000 r--p 0019f000 08:02 393714                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f18bae11000-7f18bae13000 rw-p 001a3000 08:02 393714                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f18bae13000-7f18bae17000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f18bae17000-7f18baf17000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393713                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
7f18baf17000-7f18bb116000 ---p 00100000 08:02 393713                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
7f18bb116000-7f18bb117000 r--p 000ff000 08:02 393713                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
7f18bb117000-7f18bb118000 rw-p 00100000 08:02 393713                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
7f18bb118000-7f18bb132000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393260                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
7f18bb132000-7f18bb331000 ---p 0001a000 08:02 393260                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
7f18bb331000-7f18bb333000 r--p 00019000 08:02 393260                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
7f18bb333000-7f18bb334000 rw-p 0001b000 08:02 393260                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
7f18bb334000-7f18bb33e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f18bb33e000-7f18bb343000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 529063                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7f18bb343000-7f18bb542000 ---p 00005000 08:02 529063                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7f18bb542000-7f18bb543000 rw-p 00004000 08:02 529063                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7f18bb543000-7f18bb544000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 534562                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1.0.0
7f18bb544000-7f18bb743000 ---p 00001000 08:02 534562                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1.0.0
7f18bb743000-7f18bb744000 r--p 00000000 08:02 534562                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1.0.0
7f18bb744000-7f18bb745000 rw-p 00001000 08:02 534562                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1.0.0
7f18bb745000-7f18bb748000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 530983                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7f18bb748000-7f18bb947000 ---p 00003000 08:02 530983                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7f18bb947000-7f18bb948000 r--p 00002000 08:02 530983                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7f18bb948000-7f18bb949000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 530983                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7f18bb949000-7f18bb977000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 529065                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfont.so.1.4.1
7f18bb977000-7f18bbb76000 ---p 0002e000 08:02 529065                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfont.so.1.4.1
7f18bbb76000-7f18bbb77000 r--p 0002d000 08:02 529065                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfont.so.1.4.1
7f18bbb77000-7f18bbb79000 rw-p 0002e000 08:02 529065                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfont.so.1.4.1
7f18bbb79000-7f18bbc1e000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 530981                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.32.6
7f18bbc1e000-7f18bbe1d000 ---p 000a5000 08:02 530981                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.32.6
7f18bbe1d000-7f18bbe25000 r--p 000a4000 08:02 530981                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.32.6
7f18bbe25000-7f18bbe26000 rw-p 000ac000 08:02 530981                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.32.6
7f18bbe26000-7f18bbe32000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 534514                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
7f18bbe32000-7f18bc031000 ---p 0000c000 08:02 534514                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
7f18bc031000-7f18bc032000 r--p 0000b000 08:02 534514                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
7f18bc032000-7f18bc033000 rw-p 0000c000 08:02 534514                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
7f18bc033000-7f18bc03b000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 528200                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.1
7f18bc03b000-7f18bc23b000 ---p 00008000 08:02 528200                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.1
7f18bc23b000-7f18bc23c000 r--p 00008000 08:02 528200                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.1
7f18bc23c000-7f18bc23d000 rw-p 00009000 08:02 528200                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.1
7f18bc23d000-7f18bc240000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393673                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f18bc240000-7f18bc43f000 ---p 00003000 08:02 393673                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f18bc43f000-7f18bc440000 r--p 00002000 08:02 393673                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f18bc440000-7f18bc441000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 393673                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f18bc441000-7f18bc518000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393392                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.2
7f18bc518000-7f18bc718000 ---p 000d7000 08:02 393392                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.2
7f18bc718000-7f18bc719000 r--p 000d7000 08:02 393392                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.2
7f18bc719000-7f18bc722000 rw-p 000d8000 08:02 393392                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.2
7f18bc722000-7f18bc743000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393315                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f18bc743000-7f18bc943000 ---p 00021000 08:02 393315                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f18bc943000-7f18bc944000 r--p 00021000 08:02 393315                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f18bc944000-7f18bc945000 rw-p 00022000 08:02 393315                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f18bc945000-7f18bc947000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f18bc947000-7f18bc955000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393787                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.5.0
7f18bc955000-7f18bcb54000 ---p 0000e000 08:02 393787                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.5.0
7f18bcb54000-7f18bcb55000 r--p 0000d000 08:02 393787                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.5.0
7f18bcb55000-7f18bcb56000 rw-p 0000e000 08:02 393787                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.5.0
7f18bcb56000-7f18bcb76000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 393254                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f18bcb9b000-7f18bcbfb000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 76513280                   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7f18bcbfb000-7f18bcc03000 rw-s 10085e000 00:06 14729                     /dev/dri/card0
7f18bcc03000-7f18bcc0b000 rw-s 100856000 00:06 14729                     /dev/dri/card0
7f18bcc0b000-7f18bcc13000 rw-s 10084e000 00:06 14729                     /dev/dri/card0
7f18bcc13000-7f18bcc17000 rw-s 10082f000 00:06 14729                     /dev/dri/card0
7f18bcc17000-7f18bcc1b000 rw-s 10082b000 00:06 14729                     /dev/dri/card0
7f18bcc1b000-7f18bcc9b000 rw-s 10104c000 00:06 14729                     /dev/dri/card0
7f18bcc9b000-7f18bcce7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f18bcce7000-7f18bccef000 rw-s 100899000 00:06 14729                     /dev/dri/card0
7f18bccef000-7f18bcd47000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f18bcd4a000-7f18bcd4b000 rw-s 10124c000 00:06 14729                     /dev/dri/card0
7f18bcd4b000-7f18bcd53000 rw-s 100846000 00:06 14729                     /dev/dri/card0
7f18bcd53000-7f18bcd73000 rw-s 100866000 00:06 14729                     /dev/dri/card0
7f18bcd73000-7f18bcd76000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f18bcd76000-7f18bcd77000 r--p 00020000 08:02 393254                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f18bcd77000-7f18bcd78000 rw-p 00021000 08:02 393254                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f18bcd78000-7f18bcd79000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f18bcd79000-7f18bcfb4000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 533895                     /usr/bin/Xorg
7f18bd1b4000-7f18bd1b6000 r--p 0023b000 08:02 533895                     /usr/bin/Xorg
7f18bd1b6000-7f18bd1c3000 rw-p 0023d000 08:02 533895                     /usr/bin/Xorg
7f18bd1c3000-7f18bd1d4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f18bd52b000-7f18bfbaa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7fff59fc8000-7fff59fe9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff59fec000-7fff59fee000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fff59fee000-7fff59ff0000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Comment: Video RAM(VRAM) is *massively* faster than RAM.

Comment: VRAM is faster when accessed by the GPU but probably slower when accessed by the CPU (since the PCI-e bus has a limited bandwidth)

Comment: "The GPU memory is mmap(2)-ed, and this means in virtual memory, not physical one" - By virtual memory , you mean it can be swapped? i know that in CUDA we can have non-pageable memory aka pinned memory. Don't know whether amd driver allocates pinned or not

Comment: By virtual memory, he means that it there is no actual physical memory reserved on the CPU-side. It's just an entry in the MMU and nothing more, so you can access a virtual address space which is much larger than the physical address space. Virtual and swappable are orthogonal concepts. That being said, if you're allocating with `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR`, the AMD driver is known to pin the allocated pages, which increases data transfer performance but puts more pressure on the VM and can result in failed allocations.

Comment: "but I believe that a machine with more GPU memory than RAM is grossly unbalanced " - @BasileStarynkevitch  hmm.. i am unaware of any condition/ like that . can you explain a little bit more. thanks

Comment: I added a sentence explaining my intuitions.